# ravendb shardstrategy & shardeddocumentstore

Tags: ravendb

Can we choose to have a few objects sharded, typically which have the potential to have large amount of data and leave the others to be stored across all instances?

For example when I have a banking transaction, I might want to store the customers and transactions in different shards and I might want to store the list of bank branches in all databases. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like that, but not in a single database.
The way it works, you have two databases on each server (and two document stores) 
1) Sharded, for Transactions & Customers
2) Standard, for Banks.

The banks database is replicated to all nodes.

Comment: ok, but how do I run queries with joins in this case? Should I pull information separately from individual dbs and then reduce later?